# AES-GCM conformance test

Tags: encryption, aes, aes-gcm

Is there any conformance tests/sequences to validate AES-GCM & GHASH() implementation?

Details: I'm implementing AES-GSM, that's just for better understanding of that stuff, nothing more. Well I need to validate somehow my result. There is 'openssl' and some python libraries to do encryption but they allow to check only final encryption result and nothing else in between. I haven't seen anything at all to validate 'GHASH()' or 'multH()'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2011/bn-randall-test-vectors-0511-v1.pdf) and [here](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/master/crypto/cipher_extra/test/cipher_tests.txt) for some test vectors (the second link is actually likely a better place to start). You may have to deal with padding though.

Answer (score 4):

[gcm-spec](http://luca-giuzzi.unibs.it/corsi/Support/papers-cryptography/gcm-spec.pdf), this document has "AES Test Vectors" section in the end. There are a numerous test cases with all intermediate results for encryption and ghash. I found them a rather useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Wycheproof](https://github.com/google/wycheproof/blob/master/testvectors/aes_gcm_test.json) test vectors as well